# visibility style does not change second time click in javascript and css

Tags: javascript, css, click, toggle, visibility

I'm trying to create a responsive navbar.

When screen size is reduced I'm using media query to style visibility of #nav-items to hidden and display a menu icon.

I have written a javascript code to handle on click on menu icon style #nav-itmes to visible and hidden (trying to toggle by if condition to check style value)

Problem: on first click result is ok. #nav-items are visible but again when i click #nav-items style does not change to hidden (while i can console click event is there on every click)

Can anyone guide me ?

There are several approach to have this result to toggle an element but I want to only know what is issue in below code. (only javascript please).

```js
let nav_icon = document.getElementById("nav-icon");
nav_icon.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log('clicked');
  let nav_items = document.getElementById("nav-items");
  nav_items.style.visibility = nav_items.style.visibility = "hidden" ? "visible" : "hidden";
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

a,
ul,
h3 {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

body {
  background-image: url("/img/bg.jpg");
}

img {
  display: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  top: .4em;
  right: .2em;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #ABA9A966;
  gap: 10px;
}

nav a,
header h3 {
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  nav a,
  header h3 {
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar {
    flex-flow: column;
  }
  header {
    display: none;
  }
  nav {
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ABA9A966;
    position: fixed;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 2.5em;
    right: 0;
  }
  nav a {
    margin: 0;
    height: 22px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    display: block;
    width: 8rem;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  img {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<div class="navbar">
  <header>
    <h3>Hello Guest</h3>
  </header>
  <nav id="nav-items">
    <a href="#" class="nav-item">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Dispatch</a>
    <a href="#">Account</a>
    <a href="#">Report</a>
    <a href="#">Control</a>
  </nav>
</div>
<img src="/img/menu.png" id="nav-icon">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often you cannot see the style of an element in JS if the style was applied in a stylesheet

You can toggle a class instead

For example

```
nav { visibility: hidden; }
nav.show { visibility: visible; }
```

and js

```
const nav_icon = document.getElementById("nav-icon");
const nav_items = document.getElementById("nav-items");
nav_icon.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log('clicked');
  nav_items.classList.toggle("show")
});
```

```js
const nav_icon = document.getElementById("nav-icon");
const nav_items = document.getElementById("nav-items");
nav_icon.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log('clicked');
  nav_items.classList.toggle("show")
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

a,
ul,
h3 {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

body {
  background-image: url("/img/bg.jpg");
}

img {

  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  top: .4em;
  right: .2em;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #ABA9A966;
  gap: 10px;
}

nav { visibility: hidden; }
nav a,
header h3 {
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  nav a,
  header h3 {
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar {
    flex-flow: column;
  }
  header {
    display: none;
  }
  nav {
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ABA9A966;
    position: fixed;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 2.5em;
    right: 0;
  }
  nav a {
    margin: 0;
    height: 22px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    display: block;
    width: 8rem;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  img {
    display: block;
  }
}

nav.show {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<div class="navbar">
  <header>
    <h3>Hello Guest</h3>
  </header>
  <nav id="nav-items">
    <a href="#" class="nav-item">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Dispatch</a>
    <a href="#">Account</a>
    <a href="#">Report</a>
    <a href="#">Control</a>
  </nav>
</div>
<img src="/img/menu.png" id="nav-icon" title="ICON" alt="ICON">
```

Comment: Working perfectly, i also tried with class toggle with making two different class seperately and tried to toggle but didn't work then. But your solution to just add another class and toggle with that is working as needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Think this line is incorrect:
nav_items.style.visibility = nav_items.style.visibility = "hidden" ? "visible" : "hidden";

The equality check should be:
nav_items.style.visibility === "hidden"

so this may work:
nav_items.style.visibility = (nav_items.style.visibility === "hidden" ? "visible" : "hidden");

Comment: It worked, but now on first click nothing happens and one more click code works, and so on. Why on first click not responding, any guess ?

Answer (score -1):

Try the css property for media-query: display:none !important;

Comment: I have set visibilty style to hidden and that is working fine initially, even after i click on menu icon the result is as expected nav items visibilty shows, but issue is when click one more time there is no reponse. However I got solution as in first answer by toggle between class. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).